# Word for "measured quantity"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What is a word which refers to any number of items that exist as measured quantities in something? This is like *measurand*, similar to how *operand* is some kind of *modifier* to an overall o.

Comment: Measurand is a valid word, popular in technical circles but has not entered the dictionaries yet.

Comment: Without more context, this is Not a Real Question. It depends entirely on the particular kind of items we're talking about, and the the measuring/packaging/delivery system involved.

Comment: Wow, I thought I'd made the word up. I was hoping for a general response as I was completely stuck for ideas on what word was escaping my mental clutches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "measure" itself can mean a measured quantity. From NOAD:

> **measure** *n*
>    2 a standard unit used to express the size, amount, or degree of something: *a furlong is an obsolete measure of length* | *tables of weights and measures.*
>   • a system or scale of such units: *the original dimensions were in imperial measure.*
>   • a particular amount of something: *a measure of egg white as a binding agent.*
>   • a standard official amount of an alcoholic drink as served in a licensed establishment.

Comment: How exasperating are these upstart dictionaries that refer to furlongs as "obsolete", when everyone knows the word is in common use for lengths of horse races, and also in the common expression *[furlongs per fortnight](http://itotd.com/articles/286/furlongs-per-fortnight/)*!  (That linked page contains a gaffe of its own, referring to a *rod* as an "obscure unit of length measuring 16.5 feet."  But *rod* is so far from being obscure that, for example, canoe [portage lengths](http://www.rook.org/earl/bwca/portages/index.html#Format) are given in rods without even saying so.)

Answer (score 3):

Absent context, terms like *[datum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/datum#English)* ("a measurement of something on a scale understood by both the recorder (a person or device) and the reader"), *number*, *[statistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statistic)* ("a single item in a statistical study"), *[measurement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/measurement)* ("magnitude (or extent or amount) determined by measurement"), and previously-suggested *measure* and *measurand* are as good as any.